# assume that the power series converges in some disk |z|<R , if the sum a(z) is a zero function then all coefficient must be 0

Tags: power-series

assume that the power series $\sum a_n z^n$converges in some  disk $|z|<R$ , if the sum $a(z)$ is a zero function then all coefficient must be $0$, I am not understanding what does it mean by if the sum $a(z)$ is a zero function? please help

Answer (score 1):

It is saying the limit of this series is zero for all $z$ such that $|z|<R$.

To prove this, plug in $z=0$, to see that $a_0=0$. Then take the derivative and plug in zero to get $a_1=0$. Do induction to get the rest of the coefficients.